# Need to use function modifiers however little confuse when implement and how

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

Hi I need help for writing below auction code.
I want to use modifier however there is some changes in solidity which make me confuse.

I have mentioned below where I need changes within "//"

```
pragma solidity^0.4.18;

import './AuctionHouse.sol';

contract BidChain is AuctionHouse {

struct biddingData {
    uint endTime;
    uint highestBid;
    address bidder;
    bool initialized;
    mapping (address => bool) flaggedUsers;
}

mapping (uint => biddingData) itemToBiddingMap;

event newBidPlaced(uint itemId, uint bidAmount, address bidder);

//1. add itemOwner modifier
function initiateBid(uint _itemId, uint _endTime) public {
    //2. refactor
    require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
    itemToBiddingMap[_itemId] = biddingData(_endTime, 0, msg.sender, 
 true);
}//1. add itemOwner modifier
function initiateBid(uint _itemId, uint _endTime) public {
    //2. refactor
    require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
    itemToBiddingMap[_itemId] = biddingData(_endTime, 0, msg.sender, true);
}

//3. add itemOwner modifier
function flagUser(uint _itemId, address _flaggedUser) public {
    //4. refactor
    require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
    require(itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].initialized == true);
    itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].flaggedUsers[_flaggedUser] = true;
}

function placeBid(uint _itemId) public payable {
    require(now < itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].endTime);
    require(msg.value > itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].highestBid);

    returnBidAmount(itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].bidder, itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].highestBid);

    itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].highestBid = msg.value;
    itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].bidder = msg.sender;

    emit newBidPlaced(_itemId, msg.value, msg.sender);
}

function returnBidAmount(address _sendee, uint _amount) internal {
    _sendee.transfer(_amount);
}

//5. add itemOwner modifier
function transferItem(uint _itemId, address _newOwner) public {
    //6. refactor
    require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
    require(now > itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].endTime);

    itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId] = _newOwner;
    ownerToItemCount[_newOwner]++;
    ownerToItemCount[msg.sender]--;

    msg.sender.transfer(itemToBiddingMap[_itemId].highestBid);
}

//We already moved this modifier here for you
modifier itemOwner(uint _itemId) {
    require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
    _;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add modifier name after public like

```
function initiateBid(uint _itemId, uint _endTime) public itemOwner{
require(msg.sender == itemToOwnerMapping[_itemId]);
itemToBiddingMap[_itemId] = biddingData(_endTime, 0, msg.sender,  true);}
```

Or you can pass parameters into modifier

```
function initiateBid(uint _itemId, uint _endTime) public itemOwner(params...){//code}
```